# ASP.NET Core: how can I get Aajx to work within a ViewComponent?

Tags: c#, html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I wanted to have my comments section (including the "post comment" button) entirely contained within a `ViewComponent` so that my main page's html isn't as cluttered. Though it seems that Ajax fails to work within a `ViewComponent`.

The same code works fine in a razor page's `.cshtml`, but inside a `ViewComponent` (within my `Pages/Shared/Components/AJAXTest/Default.cshtml`, called with `@await Component.InvokeAsync("AJAXTest")`) it does nothing.

```html
<button id="buttonDemo1">THE AJAX BUTTON</button>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        //edit: threw console.log around, nothing shows up in the browser console

        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready2!!");

            var url = '@Url.Action("TEST", "ChatRoom")';

            $('#buttonDemo1').click(function () {
                console.log("THE FORBIDDEN BUTTON HAS BEEN PRESSED!");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Found the solution here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2910#issuecomment-356276338, tried it and it works.
but there's mention that Razor Components innately supports this here https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/687#issuecomment-450596259 (though I am not familiar with how to use razor components yet).

(realized that this is a Jquery related problem not an Ajax problem so the correct question to ask was "how can I get Jquery to work within a ViewComponent?" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2910#issuecomment-356276338 , tried it and it works.

> For those who just stumpled here (aka TL;DR) you just have to define a layout on the viewcomponent.

> Example:

> #### _LayoutViewComponent.cshtml:

```
@RenderBody()
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
    </script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

> ##### YourViewComponentView.cshtml

```
@model YourModel
@{
    Layout = "_LayoutViewComponent";
}

//html stuff

@section scripts
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">
//your scripting
    </script>

}
```

But there's mention that Razor Components innately supports this here: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/687#issuecomment-450596259 (though I am not familiar with how to use razor components yet). (realized that this is a Jquery related problem not an Ajax problem so the correct question to ask was "how can I get Jquery to work within a ViewComponent?" )

---

### Edit:

the only code that is required for `_LayoutViewComponent.cshtml` is:

```
@RenderBody()

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Adding the other stuff breaks bootstrap's functionality.